# How to check the used space during run of an Informatica Powercenter Workflow?

Tags: oracle, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to find out more about the space that Informatica Powercenter takes up when a Workflow is executed.

At the moment, we have a table on an Oracle server that weighs about 300 MB and has almost 1.9 million rows: we have developed a very simple ETL that reads from an SQL view pointing to the aforementioned table without transformations, and that takes the data to another Oracle table on another server.
When we open the Monitor software checking the Session info, we see the Bytes column showing this exaggerated number, which is about 23 GB.

[image: Numbers in Monitor software]

From what we understand, this is simply an **estimate** of the total bytes transmitted, both read and write. In fact, if we increased the precision of the columns (for example, from `VARCHAR2(100)` to `VARCHAR2(4000)`) and left the rows unchanged, this number would increase.

So this value of Bytes in the monitor does not represent the space actually used, is that correct? If so, is there any way to see it?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - what makes you think this an estimate? What documentation are you referencing?

Comment: This is one of the documentation on this i can find. But as per this, bytes/sec would increase when you change precision. https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/505687?language=en_US

Comment: @NickW the link posted by Koushik Roy is correct. You can easily replicate the behaviour: you can create a single column table of `VARCHAR2(10)` with 100 rows and Informatica will return about 2000 bytes (1 column * 10 of precision * 100 rows, both read and write). If you change the datataype to `VARCHAR2(4000)` the software will return 800000 bytes (1 column * 4000 of precision * 100 rows), even if the lines have not changed

Comment: So based on this, Informatica is estimating the data volume being passed through a mapping/workflow using the column metadata as the basis for the estimation. So there is no way to get the data size directly from Informatica - you'd have to query the table size directly before and after the workflow runs. Just out of interest, why do you care?

Comment: I was interested because the customer would like to monitor the space occupied at each run of the various workflows, but at this point I would say that we can rely on the size of the Oracle tables. Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Workflow Monitor what you can see is the number of rows multiplied by their total lenght defined. So if you want to have astonished audience surprised by ETL performance, declare 100 VARCHR(4000) fields with all nulls to achieve amazing performance that has nothing to do with the actual amount of data transfered.

That's it for the Workflow Monitor. Your title question refers to space used, however. So how much space is used by PowerCenter to process the data?

Check the logs. If you read the logs you will find entries mentioning the files getting created and space allocated. There is also another way, knowing the names of the files from the logs, but you can check that ONLY while the workflow is running. You need to check the cache (*.idx and *.dat) files created in temp and cache infashared folders (for joiners, sorters, lookups, aggregators). Do note that files are removed after workflow is successfully completed, so you'd need to catch that during the execution.

Please also note that ideally, no data (almost) will be cached and all rows read from source will be written to target without storing data in the middle. This is of course ideal situation when no caching transformations are used.

So, there are two topics here:

- Workflow Monitor showing the number of rows processed (accurate) and throughput in bytes (completely fake, simply rows * declared row lenght)
- Space used while processing data, that can be checked in the logs and on file system to get precise numbers.